# Write an expression for $(\cos θ + i\sin θ)^4$ using De Moivre’s Theorem.

Tags: complex-numbers

Obtain another expression for $(\cos θ + i \sin θ)^4$ by direct multiplication (i.e., expand the bracket). Use the two expressions to show 
$$
\cos 4\theta = 8 \cos^4 \theta − 8 \cos^2 \theta + 1,\\
\sin 4\theta = 8\cos^3\theta \sin\theta − 4 \cos \theta\sin \theta.
$$
You may use the well-known identity: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, but do not use any multiple angle formula.

I got using DMT that $(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^4 = (cos 4\theta + i\sin 4\theta)$
and using direct multiplication, I got $\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta - 4\cos^3\theta*\sin\theta*i - 4\cos\theta \sin^3\theta i - 6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$

Comment: ...so...? What did you get?

Comment: De Moirve's theorem tells us that $(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^n = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)$ but your question doesn't say to use but to expand. If you are going to expand, I would recommend using exponentials.

Comment: It does. It says to use both ways to show that cos 4θ = 8 cos^4 θ − 8 cos2^ θ + 1. and to also show that sin 4θ = 8 cos^3 θ sin θ − 4 cos θ sin θ.

Answer (score 1):

By De Moivre’s theorem,
$$
(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^4=\cos 4\theta+i\sin 4\theta.
$$
On the other hand
$$
(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4
$$
Expand the binomial and equate the real and imaginary parts. Where you find $\sin^2\theta$, substitute $1-\cos^2\theta$.

You have, almost correctly,
$$
\cos4\theta+i\sin4\theta=
\cos^4\theta+4i\cos^3\theta\sin\theta+6i^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta
+4i^3\cos\theta\sin^3\theta+i^4\sin^4\theta
$$
Now $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$ and $i^4=1$, so, by equating the real and imaginary parts, we get
$$
\cos4\theta=\cos^4\theta-6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta\\
\sin4\theta=4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta-4\cos\theta\sin^3\theta
$$
Now it's just a matter of substituting $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, so, for example, we have
\begin{align}
\sin4\theta&=4\sin\theta(\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta\sin^2\theta)\\
&=4\sin\theta(\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta+\cos^3\theta)\\
&=8\cos^3\theta\sin\theta-4\cos\theta\sin\theta.
\end{align}
Do similarly for $\cos4\theta$.