# How does (cosx+isinx)^4 equate to 1-8 cos^2(x)+8 cos^4(x)-4 i cos(x) sin(x)+8 i cos^3(x) sin(x)

Tags: complex-numbers

I can't figure out how (cosx+isinx)^4 expands to 1-8 cos^2(x)+8 cos^4(x)-4 i cos(x) sin(x)+8 i cos^3(x) sin(x)

I got it equal to sin^4(x)+cos^4(x)+i (4 sin(x) cos^3(x)-4 sin^3(x) cos(x))-6 sin^2(x) cos^2(x)

How do I make it equal to 1-8 cos^2(x)+8 cos^4(x)-4 i cos(x) sin(x)+8 i cos^3(x) sin(x)

Comment: No I haven't ....

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026401/write-an-expression-for-cos-θ-i-sin-θ4-using-de-moivre-s-theorem) seems *exactly* the same.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Replace $\sin^2(x)$ with $1-\cos^2(x)$ (do you know why these are equal?). Similarly, replace $\sin^3(x)$ with $\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))$, and $\sin^4(x)$ with $(1-\cos^2(x))^2$.

Answer (score 0):

expanding we get
$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^4=\cos(x)^4-6\cos(x)^2\sin(x)^2+\sin(x)^4+i(4\cos(x)^3\sin(x)-4\cos(x)\sin(x)^3)$
note that
$\cos(4x)=8\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}-8\, \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{2}+1
$
and
$\sin(4x)=8\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}\sin \left( x \right) -4
\,\cos \left( x \right) \sin \left( x \right) 
$

Comment: I know.. but how does it equal  1-8 cos^2(x)+8 cos^4(x)-4 i cos(x) sin(x)+8 i cos^3(x) sin(x)

Comment: yes see my post edit

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(\cos x + i \sin x)^4 = \left(e^{xi}\right)^4 = e^{4xi} = \cos 4x + i \sin 4x.$$

Now use $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ and $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ to express it in terms of $\sin x, \cos x$.